Multi PIVOT Select
I have the following Data Structure in my Db which stores lots of different (dynamic) values based off a formsite import, I need to write a query which will return all possible combination of values so that I can use it in further data processing.
Table structure:



ID
CODE
VALUE




1
A
z


1
B
y


1
A
x


1
C
w


1
B
v


2
A
x


2
B
y



What I would like as an output is as follows:



Id
A
B
C




1
z
y
w


1
x
y
w


1
z
v
w


1
x
v
w


2
x
y




I have tried all types of Pivoting, RowNubers, Ranks but non seem to be giving me the exact output i need.
declare @table table (ID int, Code nvarchar(10), value nvarchar(30))


insert into @table(Id,Code,Value)
values
(1,N'A',N'z'),
(1,N'B',N'y'),
(1,N'A',N'x'),
(1,N'C',N'w'),
(1,N'B',N'v'),
(2,N'A',N'x'),
(2,N'B',N'y')

select * from @table

select 
    *
into #r1
from (
    select 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by code) as RowNumberColumn ,
        id,
        code,
        value 
    from @table

) as t
pivot (
    max(value) for code in (A,B,C)
) as p
select * from #r1

select 
    * 
from #r1 as p
join #r1 as c on p.ID = c.ID and p.RowNumberColumn <> c.ID


select 
    * 
from #r1 as p
join #r1 as c on p.ID = c.ID and p.RowNumberColumn <> c.ID

select distinct 
    p.Id,
    p.RowNumberColumn,
    coalesce(c.a,p.a) as A,
    coalesce(c.b,p.b) as B,
    coalesce(c.c,p.c) as C
from #r1 as p, #r1 as c 
where p.ID = c.ID
    and (p.a <> c.a
    or p.b <> c.b
    or p.c <> c.c
    )


drop table #r1t

There will be multiple Codes which can have multiple values associated to an ID. So hard coding a number of joins is not an option

That's a PIVOT operation, not multi-dimensional SELECT. Relational tables aren't 2D grids, they're the actual relations between their values. If you want to talk about dimensions, the number of columns is the number of "dimensions". In Pandas etc you'll see PIVOT/UNPIVOT referred as converting to wide or long format

To do what you want you can use the PIVOT operator in SQL Server and all the databases that support it, or you can group the data and CASE or IIF to return the values you want in each column, eg SUM(IIF(Code='A',A,0)) AS A or MAX(IIF(Code='A',A,'')) AS A. There's not a huge difference in the code you need to write either way

I'm pretty sure "further dataprocessing" code will be much more suited to handle the "combo" thing. I wouldn't call it a pivot though, it's some kind of weird amalgamation of values, because the rows have no relationship between the columns. Just don't do this in SQL

Multiple JOINs are used when UNpivoting without using the UNPIVOT command. In any case, the number of columns must be known in advance. A query can't have an arbitrary number of columns

Does your result have to have variable columns? If you can deal with a single column you could output your combinations as JSON, or similar and use a recursive CTE to get your cartesian product? Example on db<>fiddle

I found a roundabout way to solve the problem using String_AGG and then split from SQL Server split CSV into multiple rows . Now I need to find a way to make it more dynamic.
CREATE TABLE Example 
(
    ID  VARCHAR(512),
    CODE    VARCHAR(512),
    VALUE   VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO Example (ID, CODE, VALUE) VALUES
    ('1', 'A', 'z'),
    ('1', 'B', 'y'),
    ('1', 'A', 'x'),
    ('1', 'C', 'w'),
    ('1', 'B', 'v'),
    ('2', 'A', 'x'),
    ('2', 'B', 'y');

SELECT * FROM Example

SELECT * 
INTO #TEMP  
FROM (
  SELECT
    [ID],
    [CODE],
    String_AGG([Value],', ') as Value
  FROM Example
  GROUP BY ID,[CODE] 
) Results
PIVOT (
  min(Value)
  FOR [CODE]
  IN ([A],[B],[C])
) AS PivotTable 
  
SELECT ID,Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) 'A' 
INTO #TEMPA  
FROM  
(
     -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
     SELECT ID, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(A, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM #TEMP     
) A1
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(A)

SELECT ID,Ltrim(Split.b.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) 'B' 
INTO #TEMPB
FROM  
(
     -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
     SELECT ID, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(B, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM #TEMP     
) AS B2
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(B)


SELECT ID,Ltrim(Split.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) 'C' 
INTO #TEMPC  
FROM  
(
     -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
     SELECT ID, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(C, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM #TEMP     
) AS C3 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(C)
  

SELECT A.ID, A,B,C FROM
#TEMPA A 
LEFT JOIN #TEMPB B ON (A.ID=B.ID)
LEFT JOIN #TEMPC C ON (C.ID=A.ID OR C.ID=B.ID)

fiddle



ID
A
B
C




1
z
y
w


1
z
v
w


1
x
y
w


1
x
v
w


2
x
y
null




Your answer contradicts your own requirement: "hard coding a number of joins is not an option", as you have hard coded your joins, and the codes in this answer. If that is an option there is a much simpler way of doing this, by just joining to your original table, combining your values only to split them again later is redundant. Simple example on db<>fiddle

Its a shame the OP won't make due with CSV results or this would work https://dbfiddle.uk/OQyvdrhB

@BartMcEndree, While your solution in the comment (not the answer) doesnt fit my need exactly, I have resolved my issue by joining the multi values with Stuff.  I have nearly 5million records to pivot, which is why i wanted to try and see if SO had a different way to what I was thinking. Thanks for providing that.

A CSV result format helps solves the dynamic column requirement.
CREATE TABLE Example 
(
    ID  VARCHAR(512),
    CODE    VARCHAR(512),
    VALUE   VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO Example (ID, CODE, VALUE) VALUES
    ('1', 'A', 'z'),
    ('1', 'B', 'y'),
    ('1', 'A', 'x'),
    ('1', 'C', 'w'),
    ('1', 'B', 'v'),
    ('2', 'A', 'x'),
    ('2', 'B', 'y');

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.CODE) 
            FROM Example c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

  set @query = 'SELECT ID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
  SELECT
    [ID],
    [CODE],
    String_AGG([Value],'', '') as Value
  FROM Example
  GROUP BY ID,[CODE] 
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Value)
                for CODE in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
  
execute(@query)

fiddle



ID
A
B
C




1
z,x
y,v
w


2
x
y
null




The premise of your query is a simple cartesian product, which you can create with multiple joins:
SELECT  t.ID, 
        A = t1.value, 
        B = t2.value, 
        C = t3.value
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM @table) AS t
        LEFT JOIN @table AS t1
            ON  t1.ID = t.ID
            AND t1.Code = 'A'
        LEFT JOIN @table AS t2
            ON  t2.ID = t.ID
            AND t2.Code = 'B'
        LEFT JOIN @table AS t3
            ON  t3.ID = t.ID
            AND t3.Code = 'C';

As long as your actual table has an index on (ID, Code) with value as a non key column you should get reasonable performance here. This is not dynamic though and requires that you know all the codes first, and is limited to 3 columns. It is however fairly trivial to dynamically produce this SQL so that if further codes are added, further columns are added:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T;
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT, Code NVARCHAR(10), value NVARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO #T(ID, Code, value)
VALUES
    (1, N'A', N'z'),
    (1, N'B', N'y'),
    (1, N'A', N'x'),
    (1, N'C', N'w'),
    (1, N'B', N'v'),
    (2, N'A', N'x'),
    (2, N'B', N'y'),
   -- Additional Codes added for test purposes
    (3, N'A', N'1'),
    (3, N'B', N'2'),
    (3, N'C', N'3'),
    (3, N'D', N'4'),
    (3, N'E', N'5'),
    (3, N'E', N'6');

DECLARE @CrLf CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    = (SELECT   CONCAT('SELECT t.ID, ',
                        STRING_AGG(CONCAT(QUOTENAME(t.Code), ' = t', t.RowNum, '.value'), ','), @CrLf,
                        'FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #T) AS t ', @CrLf,
                        STRING_AGG(CONCAT('LEFT JOIN #T AS t', t.RowNum, ' ON t', t.RowNum, '.ID = t.ID AND t', t.RowNum, '.Code = ''', t.Code, ''''), @CrLf), ';')
        FROM    (SELECT t.Code, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.Code) FROM #T AS t GROUP BY t.Code) AS t);


PRINT @Sql;
EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @Sql;

This automatically creates the additional joins required with SQL that looks like:
SELECT t.ID, [A] = t1.value,[B] = t2.value,[C] = t3.value,[D] = t4.value,[E] = t5.value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #T) AS t 
LEFT JOIN #T AS t1 ON t1.ID = t.ID AND t1.Code = 'A' 
LEFT JOIN #T AS t2 ON t2.ID = t.ID AND t2.Code = 'B' 
LEFT JOIN #T AS t3 ON t3.ID = t.ID AND t3.Code = 'C' 
LEFT JOIN #T AS t4 ON t4.ID = t.ID AND t4.Code = 'D' 
LEFT JOIN #T AS t5 ON t5.ID = t.ID AND t5.Code = 'E';

Which gives the result:



ID
A
B
C
D
E




1
z
y
w
NULL
NULL


1
z
v
w
NULL
NULL


1
x
y
w
NULL
NULL


1
x
v
w
NULL
NULL


2
x
y
NULL
NULL
NULL


3
1
2
3
4
5


3
1
2
3
4
6



Another option that does not require dynamic SQL but does deal with variable number of codes is to return JSON. It depends on how you do your "additional processing", but it is possible you may find this easier since your SQL returns the same number of columns regardless:
WITH RankedData AS
(   SELECT  *,
            CodeRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY t.Code)
    FROM    dbo.T AS t
), Combinations AS
(   SELECT  rd.ID, 
            rd.CodeRank,
            Level = 1,
            Json = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CONCAT('"', rd.Code, '":"', rd.value, '"'))
    FROM    RankedData AS rd
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  rd.ID, 
            rd.CodeRank,
            Level = c.Level + 1,
            Json = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CONCAT(c.Json, ', "', rd.Code, '":"', rd.value, '"'))
    FROM    RankedData AS rd
            INNER JOIN Combinations AS c
                ON c.ID = rd.ID
                AND c.CodeRank = rd.CodeRank - 1
)
SELECT  ID,  Json = JSON_ARRAY(STRING_AGG(CONCAT('{', c.Json, '}'), ','))
FROM    Combinations AS c
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Combinations AS c2 WHERE c2.ID = c.ID AND c2.Level > c.Level)
GROUP BY ID;

Which returns:



ID
Json




1
["{"A":"x", "B":"v", "C":"w"},{"A":"x", "B":"y", "C":"w"},{"A":"z", "B":"v", "C":"w"},{"A":"z", "B":"y", "C":"w"}"]


2
["{"A":"x", "B":"y"}"]


3
["{"A":"1", "B":"2", "C":"3", "D":"4", "E":"6"},{"A":"1", "B":"2", "C":"3", "D":"4", "E":"5"}"]



Examples on db<>fiddle

I did try the second but as there is nearly 5million records to run the pivot  on it was not performant at all.  I ended up doing something like your first response, and pivoting those takes about 20Seconds.
